# If column B cell value contains A cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns A and B in excel and I want third column output to be like show below

```
    A    B         C
    -------------------
    a |  sd      | a.com
    d |  a.com   |
    f |  g.in    |
    g |  ad      | g.in
```

B column has 'a.com'which contains 'a.' so C column it displays a.com 
.B column doesnt have which contains 'd.' so  column cell is empty and so on..

Comment: Should the letters from A be checked for presence in B strings for BEFORE `.` part only? i.e. `a.com` has a, but `sd` does NOT have d, while `d.com` does?

Comment: yes, d.com does. It has to be checked BEFORE . part only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following formula in column C:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(A1,LEFT($B$1:$B$4,SEARCH(".",$B$1:$B$4)-1),0)),"")
```

It is an array formula, so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in C1 copied down

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&".*",B$1:B$4,1,0),"")`

`IFERROR` function only works in Excel 2007 or later - for earlier excel versions try

`=LOOKUP("zzz",IF({1,0},"",VLOOKUP(A1&".*",B$1:B$4,1,0)))`